# Surface Charge distribution and the direction of electric field inside a current carrying wire

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electricity, electric-fields

This portion will contain two questions that seems very confusing while studying the electrodynamics.

1. My first question is like this that when we talk about the surface charges on a current carrying wire,  then how is this possible to get the negative charge on the one side of the wire and the positive charge on the other side? It's a closed circuit and not a capacitor in which there is a charge difference between the both plates. Why do these charges separate like this? Lets assume that the charges got separated somehow, and If we visualize the scenario that the battery pulls the electrons from one side and put on the other side of the wire and also the drift velocity of an electron is too low so how can it be very fast to accumulate so fast so that it's just a matter of some milliseconds or may be even less than that, What can be the perfect explanation for this so that it becomes easy to visualize whats actually going on there?
2. And the second question goes here the same as stated in the title. Being more clear to my statement, when I ask someone about why the electric field is created $⊥$ to the cross-section of the wire then they the tell me that it something has to do with the gauss law, I got number of the explanations on this website too, but the explanations and the reasons vary widely with the individuals who are actually answering this equivalent question. How the gauss law works here? And if we consider that wire a hollow cylinder (as the charges are now on the surface, we can assume the wire as a hollow cylinder so now it doesn't matter if it's a solid cylinder or a hollow cylinder while talking about the electric field formed inside) so the electric field inside this cylinder must be zero not perpendicular to the cross-section but that intuition is not true at all. Infact there must be some electric field that might be accelerating those electrons to move throughout the loop.